# Acceptable Ratio for Dev hours vs. Debugging hours?

Tags: debugging, testing

On a recent project, with roughly 6,000 hours of development, a little over 1,000 hours has gone towards "debugging"/"fixes"... does this sound to be acceptable, high or low??

I also understand that this is a rather dynamic question, while also requesting a rather simply answer, however, I'm just looking for a rough estimate/average based on past project experiences : )

Grateful for any and all input~!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pressman (2000)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Software-Engineering-Practitioners-published-McGraw-Hill/dp/B00EKYYYHM/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1398708438&sr=1-1&keywords=pressman%202000) gives 30-40% as the total amount of project time for integration, testing an debugging, so your figures look a little low - but it depends on how you calculate it!